# I am recieving an error when I try to use the sort_by method on my array of hashes. How do i solve this?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash, enumeration

At the end of this method, I have created I have tried to sort_by cohorts. However when I do this it throws back an error saying:

```
directory.rb:75: syntax error, unexpected ']'
bycohort = students.sort_by { |v| v[cohort:] }
```

I have tried this sort_by method a number of ways including:

```
 bycohort = students.sort_by { |k,v| v[cohort:] }
```

Please, could someone tell me how this method works and why. I'm confused.

```
def input_students
  puts "Please enter the names and then the cohort of the students"
  puts "To finish, just hit return twice"
  #created an empty array
  students = []
  #getting the first name
  name = gets.chomp
  cohort = gets.chomp.to_sym
     if cohort.empty?
         cohort = :november
     end

     if cohort !~ /january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december/
puts "Please enter a valid month"
puts "Warning months are case sensitive. Please enter in lowercase characters."
 cohort = gets.chomp.to_sym
end

while !name.empty? do
# add the student hash to the array called students
students << {name: name, cohort: cohort}
puts "Now we have #{students.count} students"
#getting another name from the user
name = gets.chomp
cohort = gets.chomp.to_sym

if cohort.empty?
  cohort = :november
end

if cohort !~ /january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december/
  puts "Please enter a valid month"
  puts "Warning months are case sensitive. Please enter in lowercase characters."
   cohort = gets.chomp.to_sym
end

end
  bycohort = students.sort_by { |v| v[cohort:] }
  bycohort
end
```

Comment: Your issue is not using the method wrong, but using the index incorrectly. Hash indexing is like this `v[:cohort]` not `v[cohort:]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not

```
bycohort = students.sort_by { |v| v[cohort:] }
```

but

```
bycohort = students.sort_by { |v| v[:cohort] }
```

This is the right syntax. `{ key: value }` is the literal syntax to create an hash with a symbol key but this is not the case.

Comment: @JackKelly If it makes things less confusing you can also assign things in a hash like this: `a = {:key => value}`

Comment: Thanks Eli, I'll probably start doing that for simplicities sake.

Comment: @JackKelly: The general syntax for a hash literal is `{ key => value }` (but you can drop the braces if the hash literal is the last argument to a method call). If `key` is a symbol then you can say `{ key: value }` but this only applies if the key is a symbol literal and you're writing a hash literal. Symbol literals have a leading colon everywhere else. This is a very common source of confusion with Ruby.